# Build Nuxt.js on production required devDependences

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js

- I use nuxt.js with TypeScript.
- On my local machine I use `nuxt` (start dev server).
- On production: `nuxt build` + `nuxt start`.
- Production environment has variable `NODE_ENV=production`.
- And `yarn install` on production installs packages from `dependencies` but not from `devDependencies`.

But `build` required packages from `devDependencies` (`@nuxt/typescript-build` and etc).

- [Here](https://typescript.nuxtjs.org/guide/setup/#installation) they recommend install those packages as `--dev`
- Nuxt in console told me: "Module @nuxt/typescript-build not found. Please ensure @nuxt/typescript-build is in devDependencies and installed. HINT: During build step, for npm/yarn, NODE_ENV=production or --production should NOT be used."
- But it doesn't make sense because `yarn install` already doesn't install `devDependencies`

Of course, I can copy `devDependencies` to `dependencies` and relax. But where is the right way?

Comment: What are the issues you're still facing?

Comment: @kissu I still face the problems described above

Comment: Can you react to my answer? Try to help us both debug your code? Or do you have a [repro] maybe?

Comment: Hey, any news so far?

Comment: I have this problem as well. Instead of the env var, I try to install the project on production deployment with npm i --production. '@nuxt/typescript-build' and some other packages indicated inside the buildModules are required even during this process. I understand if the idea is that these are required direct dependencies. But then why the error message says to install them as 'dev dependencies' ?

Answer (score 0):

`yarn` do install `devDependecies` too because some of them will be needed during build time, they will just not be used when the app will be running in production. For TS, you'll need the package written in the documentation but as a `buildModules`. Hence the error of the **module** not being found.

Double check this line

```js
buildModules: ['@nuxt/typescript-build']
```

So yeah, if you do not install the `dev` package, it will not be available during the build time.

Also, as suggested to you, you should not force a env flag because this is done for you already.